# On the conjecture : $|m^2-n^3|>\frac{1}{5}\sqrt[6]{m^2+n^3}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities

Let $m,n$ be positive integers, such that $m^2\neq n^3$. I conjecture   the inequality
$$|m^2-n^3|>\dfrac{1}{5}\sqrt[6]{m^2+n^3}.$$
I've tried a lot of numbers, and they all seem to work, but how do I prove it?

Comment: This question (possibly with $1/5$ replaced by a different constant) is open: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_conjecture An example listed at the end of the page pretty surely shows your constant is not good enough, but I didn't check

Comment: Between n^3 and (n+1)^3 there are at most two squares for which the inequality could fail. I would be impressed if you could show there is at most one square in this interval for which it could fail.  Gerhard "Set The Bar Lower Some" Paseman, 2020.04.09.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As suggested by **Joe Silverman**, there are counterexamples in my paper

> Rational points near curves and small nonzero $|x^3-y^2|$ via lattice reduction, *Lecture Notes in Computer Science* **1838** (proceedings of ANTS-4, 2000; W.Bosma, ed.), 33-63.  arXiv: math.NT/0005139 (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005139)

The best one there, which I think still holds the record for the largest ratio
$n^{1/2} / |m^2-n^3|$ known, is
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
m & \!\! = \!\! & 447884928428402042307918, \cr
n & \!\! = \!\! & 5853886516781223,
\end{array}
$$
with
$$
|m^2-n^3| < \frac{1}{52.3}\sqrt[6]{m^2+n^3}.
$$

Answer (score 16):

As noted in the comments, this is a version of a conjecture originally made by Marshall Hall many years ago. The original conjecture was that there is a constant $k$ so that if $m^2\ne n^3$, then 
$$ |m^2-n^3| > k \sqrt{|n|}. $$
As noted on Elkies' webpage (http://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/hall.html), this is widely believed to be false. In any case, Elkies used a clever search algorithm and a fair amount of computer time to find examples showing that $k$ would need to be quite small.

What is believed to be true is: **Strong Hall Conjecture:** For every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $k_\epsilon$ so that
$$ |m^2-n^3| > k_\epsilon \sqrt{|n|}^{1-\epsilon}
\quad\text{for all $m,n\in\mathbb Z$ with $m^2\ne n^3$}. $$ 
This is an easy consequence of the $ABC$-conjecture. One might ask if it's possible to replace the $\epsilon$ power with something like
$$ |m^2-n^3| > k_\epsilon \sqrt{|n|}\cdot (\log|n|)^{-c_\epsilon}. $$

Comment: Shouldn't the strong conjecture have $1-\epsilon$ in the exponent?

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks.I fixed it.  I'm used to writing it as $|n| \le \text{Disc}^{2+\epsilon}$, since the upper bound for $n$ is the way it usually used in applications.